# How to remote SSH into a MacOS or Linux terminal using the Termius app?

Tags: ssh, termius

I have been playing with the Termius app on Android running downloaded shell scripts that I wrote, `cat`ting files and snooping inside my device's directories; among other goofy stuff.

I have seen in some tutorials that I can remote SSH into my computer's terminal and run commands into my Android's Termius as if I'm typing on my computer's keyboard.
Having attempted these instructions myself, I've found they're no good (IMHO) and I couldn't make them work. Also, these tutorials have no good explanation for how I am actually SSHing using the Termius app.

The question is: **How do I make it work and how does it work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to:

- [generate a key on Termius](https://docs.termius.com/termius-handbook/connecting-to-a-host/keychain#generate-a-key) (and export it)
- add that key to your Mac or Linux remote user `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- connect to the remote computer using `ssh remoteUser@remoteIP`

That assume you have an ssh daemon listening on that remote computer.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Thank you for your answer!